# Does ionice work with the deadline scheduler?

Tags: linux, performance

My Debian Wheezy systems use the `deadline` scheduler.  I'm accustomed to using `ionice` to reschedule the I/O priority of disk-intensive jobs at busy times, and anecdotally this seems to help (but I don't have any hard evidence).

The [`ionice` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice), [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/ioprio.txt) and [this OpenSUSE document](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-tuning_sd_draft/cha.tuning.io.html) all suggest that only the `cfq` scheduler takes into account `ionice` interventions.  They don't explicitly state that other schedulers ignore it, but the only one they mention is `cfq`.

Do other schedulers, in particular `deadline`, work with `ionice`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. `ionice` is a mechanism for specifying priorities. But `deadline` ignores priorities and instead simply imposes an expiration time on each I/O operation and then ensures that the operation succeeds before the expiration time is met.

More information here: [the Deadline I/O scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadline_scheduler)

> The main goal of the Deadline scheduler is to guarantee a start service time for a request. It does so by imposing a deadline on all I/O operations to prevent starvation of requests. It also maintains two deadline queues, in addition to the sorted queues (both read and write). Deadline queues are basically sorted by their deadline (the expiration time), while the sorted queues are sorted by the sector number.
>
> Before serving the next request, the deadline scheduler decides which queue to use. Read queues are given a higher priority, because processes usually block on read operations. Next, the deadline scheduler checks if the first request in the deadline queue has expired. Otherwise, the scheduler serves a batch of requests from the sorted queue. In both cases, the scheduler also serves a batch of requests following the chosen request in the sorted queue.
>
> By default, read requests have an expiration time of 500 ms, write requests expire in 5 seconds.

Comment: I have written a solution to switch to the `bfq` scheduler, at least for Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/1350605/174414