# Does ionice also apply to i/o redirections?

Tags: io-redirection, ionice

A coworker recently observed a command:

`user@host:~$ ionice -c 3 mysqldump -uredacted -p redacted redacted > redacted.dmp`

Since the host in question uses the `deadline` scheduler anyway, [`ionice` is ignored](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136226/137794). However, the question was posed:

Does `ionice` also apply to the `>` redirection? Does it apply to the entire command, or just the `mysqldump`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirection is set up (file is opened) by the parent shell, before the command starts. `ionice` only affects the current shell (`mysqldump`), not the parent shell.